# BPM Process Designer no inicia

Tags: eclipse

Mi programa no arranca tengo la duda de que puede ser ya que lo e des instalado e instalado y no arranca, inicio sesión con el usuario y contraseña pero se queda cargando y se queda en blanco.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrian ayudar tengo windows 10.

Comment: cuanta ram tienes?

Comment: tengo  8gb de ram

Comment: que version de java tienes?

Answer (score 0):

1 revisa que el archiv etc / hosts esté configurado para resolver el dominio de tu servidor BPM
2 revisa el archivo de configuración .ini de tu eclipse debe apuntar al servidor BPM
3 revisa que tu proxi o red tenga conexion hacia el servidor BPM